# Java Servlet - 404 errors

Tags: tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

My system has Tomcat seven and all the files are under webapps. How can I avoid this kind of page ? So, here are my mvc :

**Web.xml :**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NouvelleAnnonce</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.forum.servlets.NouvelleAnnonce</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NouvelleAnnonce</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nouvelleannonce</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**com.forum.servlets.NouvelleAnnonce.java**

```
public class NouvelleAnnonce extends HttpServlet {  
    public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/nouvelleannonce.jsp";    
    public static final String BAN = "/WEB-INF/banni.jsp";  
    public static final String ATT_USER = "utilisateur";    
    public static final String ATT_FORM = "formnouvelle";   
    public static final String CMPT_J = "j";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)             throws ServletException, IOException {      
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();         
        Utilisateur utilisateur = (Utilisateur) session.getAttribute("utilisateur");

        if (utilisateur.getNiveauuser() != 0) 
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response); 
        else 
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(BAN).forward(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)            throws ServletException, IOException {      
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();         
        Utilisateur utilisateur = (Utilisateur) session.getAttribute("utilisateur");

        AnnonceDAO<com.forum.beans.Annonce, Integer> td = new AnnonceDAO<com.forum.beans.Annonce, Integer>();
        TopicForm form = new TopicForm();       
        com.forum.beans.Annonce t = form.creerAnnonce(request); 
        List<com.forum.beans.Annonce> tl = utilisateur.getAnnonceList();

        request.setAttribute(ATT_FORM, form);

        try {           
            if (utilisateur.getAnnonceList() == null)
                tl = new ArrayList<com.forum.beans.Annonce>();          
            else
                tl = utilisateur.getAnnonceList();      
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            System.out.println(e);      
        }
        if (form.getErreurs().isEmpty()) {
            t.setTcreateur(utilisateur); 
            t.setDernPostuleur(utilisateur.getNom()); 
            tl.add(t);          
            utilisateur.setAnnonceList(tl);             
            td.save(t);             
            session.setAttribute(CMPT_J, 1);            
            session.setAttribute(ATT_FORM, form);           
            response.sendRedirect("/projetForum/forum?num=1");      
        } else {            
            session.setAttribute(ATT_USER, utilisateur);            
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);      
        }   
    }
}
```

**Error page :**
http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2013/08/31/130831023723838934.jpg

Comment: Please fix the code formatting. You've pressed both the code and the quote button and now the code appears as mixed quote and code. This is not right. You should only press the code button for code blocks. The quote button is intented for quote blocks. Further, please also state the concrete functional requirement and problem in own words. I'm not seeing that anywhere in the question.

Comment: @BalusC, the code has been fixed. Sorry for being incomprehensible.

Comment: with which url are you calling the page? Are you sure that the resource to which you forward are correctly located?